# C# equivalent of "value error" in Python

Tags: c#, python, error-handling

Is there a C# error exception for a value error? the equivalent of the python "value error" below?

```
    except ValueError as e:
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sounds like you probably want [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) depending on the precise nature. (The latter exceptions are subtypes of the first.)

Comment: @bolt19 Mark the post as an answer then.

Comment: says i gotta wait another 4 mins